# Debugging in Xcode Iphone is not very effective

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, memory-management

I'm new with programming xcode and iphone. So he can that the "question" you seem silly. When I get errors in my code, such as a bad memory allocation, the debugger stops in the "hand" with an arrow written :

```
Thread 1: Program received signal:"EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
```

Are is it possible to see how this line of my code signal was launched? Because the only thing I can see in the "Call stack", are files that contain instructions like:

```
0x31dedc98 <0016> ldr r5, [r4, # 8]
```

I usually program in C++, and if you try to access a variable that is not accessible, the debugger will not show me the assembly code where the error occurred...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your symbols are being stripped. If you have a Debug configuration, use that - by default it should not strip symbols. Otherwise go into Build Settings and set **Strip Debug Symbols During Copy** to No.